# Как получить значения массива из спарсенного файла?

Tags: javascript, массивы, ajax, парсер, csv

Всем привет, знаю, вопрос очень глупый, но надеюсь на помощь. Есть cvs-файл, который нужно парсить, файл лежит на сервере и там актуальные цены.
я использую papaparse.js для парсинга, дело вот в чем, данные достать не проблема, но я не могу адекватно вытащить их из зоны видимости функции, которая срабатывает при complete, т.е. у меня пустой массив, я пытаюсь засунуть в него данные из файла, и использовать их в другой функции.

```
function parseCvs(start, end) {
price = [];
Papa.parse("/price.csv", {
  download: true,
  header: false,
  complete: function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++) {
        price.push(results.data[i][1]);
    }
    console.log(price);
  }
});
console.log(price);}
```

Т.е. первый лог выдает массив, к которому я могу обращаться по индексу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Второй же выдает такой массив, в целом меня устроит, но как получить выборочные значения в других функциях?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во-первых функция должна возвращать результат, чтобы им воспользоваться. во-вторых в консоле должен браться этот самый возвращаемый результат....и в-третьих, проблема ещё и в асинхронщине - это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/191482

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)